# AspectJ: How to get class  localization from JoinPoint?

Tags: java, aspectj

Can I get class localization from JoinPoint?

I tried to use

`joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString()` 
`joinPoint.getThis().getClass().getSimpleName()` 
`joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()`

but I all I got was:

`RMIServer.main(..)`

but I need something like

`project1.package1.package2.RMIServer`

Is it possible to obtain that information from JoinPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used: `jp.getSignature().toLongString()` and I got:
`public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])`

instead of  using `joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString()` (result `MIClient.main(..)`)

Answer (score 0):

use this one example code:

```
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getProtectionDomain();
    String path = protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm();
```

Comment: Any idea why I get `NullPointerException` in   `ProtectionDomain protectionDomain` `=joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getProtectionDomain();`?

Comment: check this joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() for NPE first - what is the result?

Comment: `joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()` in `null`

Comment: and what about joinPoint.getThis().getClass() - what is the result?

Comment: `joinPoint.getThis().getClass()` is `null` too

Answer (score 0):

Check this ...

```
MyClass mc = (MyClass)jointPoint.getTarget();
```